# MySQL Constraint Check

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I created a table using the following query:

```
CREATE Table articulo
(
 id_art int NOT NULL,
 nom_art varchar (25) DEFAULT 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 prec_art decimal (10,5) DEFAULT 0.000,
 peso_art decimal (10,5),
 existencia float,
 color_art int, CONSTRAINT chk_color1 CHECK (color_art between 0 and 20),
 um_art varchar (10) DEFAULT 'DEF_PZA',
 primary key (id_art)
);
```

Then, I tested the Constraint with the following line of code:

```
INSERT into articulo values (80,'Taza',70.254,10.00,10.00,25,'PZA');
```

What I see is that the constraint is not working. I can insert 25 without any problem. I looked up for topics about this here and found that:

> The MySQL Reference Manual says:
>
> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.
>
> Try a trigger...

I am begginer with SQL, do you have any suggestion to implement this check constraint instead of using triggers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL accepts `constraint` syntax . . . but then doesn't do anything.  If you want to learn about `constraints`, you'll need to use another database.

Comment: What DB do you recommend? I would prefer any except from SQL Server

Comment: Postgres, Oracle, and SQL Server (at least) all have free versions that support `check` constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check constraint does not work work as expected in mysql. check the bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464.

You can have an alternative solution like follows to set a default value

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_color_art_check BEFORE INSERT ON articulo
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF (NEW.color_art < 0 OR NEW.color_art > 25 )THEN 
SET NEW.color_art=0; 
END IF; 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, you can replace a CHECK constraint with a table and a foreign key constraint. This case is one of them.

```
create table art_color (
  color_art integer not null,
  primary key (color_art)
);

insert into art_color values
(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10),
(11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20);

CREATE Table articulo
(
 id_art int NOT NULL,
 nom_art varchar (25) DEFAULT 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 prec_art decimal (10,5) DEFAULT 0.000,
 peso_art decimal (10,5),
 existencia float,
 color_art int, 
 CONSTRAINT chk_color1 
   foreign key (color_art) references art_color (color_art),
 um_art varchar (10) DEFAULT 'DEF_PZA',
 primary key (id_art)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of MySQL storage engines constraint checks are not implemented yet(even after 15 years of development, yeah..). Just as many other features of mature RDBMS. Maybe they will be implemented in next decade, maybe not..

Use triggers instead as error text and [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) say's.